# google maps API v3 set marker and get point

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a problem to set marker and get latitude and longitude for that marker. How can I do that in google maps v3 API

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("divGoogleMaps"), myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {

});
```

this is my start code.

Answer (score 4):

You should check Google Maps API doc web-site they have a fex example to help you started.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
          placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
        });
      }

      function placeMarker(position, map) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: position,
          map: map
        });
        map.panTo(position);
      }
```

Here you set a marker and get the position.

Comment: at the end this code help me do the thing. i can have only one marker on map and this marker is set when user cliks on map 'code' google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) {
    if(self.marker != null)
     self.marker.setMap(null);
    self.value = new google.maps.LatLng( event.latLng.lat() , event.latLng.lng()); 
    self.marker = new  google.maps.Marker({
     position:self.value
    });
    self.zoom = map.getZoom();
    self.marker.setMap(map);
  });

Answer (score 0):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng, 
  map: map, 
  title:"Hello World!"
});
```

Taken directly from [Google Maps API v3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers)

If you want to attach an event listener to the marker, it is advisable to do it right after you add it to the map, while you still have a fresh reference to it (in the case where you're potentially looping through some marker adding code, as is common).

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) {
    if(self.marker != null)
     self.marker.setMap(null);
    self.value = new google.maps.LatLng( event.latLng.lat() , event.latLng.lng()); 
    self.marker = new  google.maps.Marker({
     position:self.value
    });
    self.zoom = map.getZoom();
    self.marker.setMap(map);
  });